# image field with forms is not submitting the image

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

i have a comment model in my django. i'm just using the content to submitting with the form but now i want to submit the image also. But its not working i've trying it many ways but its not working.

views.py:

```
def post_detail(request, pk):
posts = get_object_or_404(post, pk=pk)
comments = Comment.objects.filter(post=posts, reply=None,).order_by('-timestamp')
#post=posts is the above post details posts its mean post for the exact corresponding posts
is_liked = False
if posts.likes.filter(id=request.user.id).exists():
    is_liked = True


if request.method == 'POST':
    comment_form = CommentForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
    if comment_form.is_valid():
        content = request.POST.get('content')
        image = request.FILES['image']
        reply_id = request.POST.get('comment_id')
        comment_qs = None
        if reply_id:
            comment_qs = Comment.objects.get(id=reply_id)
        comment = Comment.objects.create(post=posts, user=request.user, content=content, image=image, reply=comment_qs,)
        comment.save()
        notify.send(request.user, recipient=posts.author, actor=request.user, verb='comment in your post', target=posts, nf_type='comment_by_one_user')

else:
    comment_form = CommentForm()
context = {'posts':posts, 'comments':comments, 'comment_form':comment_form, 'is_liked': is_liked, 'total_likes': posts.total_likes(),}

if request.is_ajax():
    html = render_to_string('blog/comments.html', context, request=request)
    return JsonResponse({'form': html})

return render(request, 'blog/post_detail.html', context)
```

and my froms.py:

```
class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
content = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Text goes here', 'rows': '4', 'cols': '10'}))

class Meta:
    model = Comment
    fields = ('content', 'image',)
```

the image is not submitting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please share your template code. But I can guess the problem. You didn't include multipart/form-data in form tag. This is common mistake everyone is doing.Please include and if you did please share your html code.

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
  ------
  Your code 

  -----
  </form>
```

Happy Coding :-)